# Get convex hull of polygons if they are within a certain distance of each other otherwise leave their geometries alone

Tags: postgis, distance, convex-hull

What the question says, I want to join geometries together (as a convex hull) if they are within a certain distance of each other, and leave them as separate geometries if they have no neighbors within that distance.

If it makes any difference these geometries start out as centroids, but can be buffered to form polygons. I ultimately want the resulting geometries to be buffered polygons.

I was thinking I could use some sort of `CASE` statement and select geometries based on distance like: `AND (geom1 <-> geom2) < distance_threshold`, but I couldn't get it to select anything.

Comment: My guess is that your data is in a geographic coordinate system like WGS84 (4326).  That means that the distance units are degrees and probably all less than your threshold distance value.  You need to cast your geom to geography to do the distance search in meters.  Also look at `st_clusterwithin` and `st_clusterdbscan` to do the clustering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ST_ClusterWithinWin`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.4/ST_ClusterWithinWin.html) to cluster the points by distance, and then compute the convex hull (and the buffer if desired) of the clusters.

```
WITH data(id, geom) AS (VALUES
   (1, 'POINT (10 10)'::geometry)
  ,(2, 'POINT (10 20)'::geometry)
  ,(3, 'POINT (20 20)'::geometry)
  ,(4, 'POINT (70 80)'::geometry)
  ,(5, 'POINT (80 80)'::geometry)
  ,(6, 'POINT (70 70)'::geometry)
  ,(7, 'POINT (30 80)'::geometry)
  ,(8, 'POINT (60 30)'::geometry)
  ,(9, 'POINT (70 30)'::geometry)
  ,(10, 'POINT (80 30)'::geometry)
  ,(11, 'POINT (20 50)'::geometry)
),
clusters AS (SELECT geom, ST_ClusterWithinWin(geom, 10) OVER () AS cluster_id 
  FROM data)
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)), 10) AS hull 
FROM clusters 
GROUP BY cluster_id;
```

[image]

In older PostGIS versions `ST_ClusterWithin` must be used, which provides the clusters as an array of collections.

Comment: In older versions you would want to use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` with `minpoints = 0` - honestly this new window function is a convenience wrapper I don't really understand, and with that name, too... Of note is that, if OP wants cluster rules applied *on the buffers,* either buffer in advance or add the desired buffer distance to the cluster distance.

Comment: Thanks @dr_jts, this is exactly what I was looking for.